# Getting the path of a module in node (the module folder, not the entry file)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to be able to look up the path to a module at build time in node.

I saw in the docs there is `require.resolve` like this

```
// get path to module 'foo'
console.log(require.resolve('foo'));
```

but that looks for path to the entry point of the module. If the module has no entry point (it's just a collection of shared files) then `require.resolve` fails.

I know in some cases I could just look in `node_modules/name-of-module` but in various circumstances that would be wrong. For example I have 'foo' as a dependency and 'foo' as a 'bar' as a dependency. Then by default bar will be in `project-root/node_modules/bar` but if I `npm link` 'foo' then 'bar' will be in `project-root/node_modules/foo(link)/node_modules/bar`

I thought about putting a dummy entry and that works for my own modules but it doesn't work for modules that I don't control.

Is there some way to find the path to the root folder of a given module?

Also is there a way to get the path to a module from the context of some other module.

In other words, normally if I do

```
const bar = require('bar');
```

That's the going to get the 'bar' module referenced in my package.json. Imagine there is some other package 'foo' that includes a different version of 'bar'. I want to be able to ask "what is the path that for 'bar' that package 'foo' would get?"

The actual problem I'm try to solve is to *at build time* copy some files from some module into my build's output folder but to do that I need to be able to find the module.

I can hack something together but it would be nice to do it the "correct" way assuming their is a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for a direct dependency I can do this

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function exists(filename) {
  try {
    const stat = fs.statSync(filename);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

function getModulePath(name) {
  for (const dirname of require.resolve.paths(name)) {
    const filename = path.join(dirname, name);
    if (exists(filename)) {
      return filename;
    }
  }
}
```

For a indirect dependency I have to make the direct dependency do the look up. At least for the `npm link` case mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would to the trick:

```
function pathForModuleAsAnotherModule(get, another) {
    let m = require('module')
    let anotherLocation = require.resolve(another);
    let anotherDir = require('path').dirname(anotherLocation);
    let anotherPaths = m.Module._nodeModulePaths(anotherDir)
    return require.resolve(get, { paths: anotherPaths })
}
```

And then:

```
pathForModuleAsAnotherModule('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: Thanks but as pointed out in question `require.resolve(another)` doesn’t work because it expects an entry point.

Comment: Then it is not posiible. You don't know wheather it is 'node_modules/xxx' (npm) or 'node_modules/aaa/node_modules/xxx' (pnpm) or '/home/user/node_modules/xxx' (npm install of xxx with package.json there)